# for loop asks user for input 5 times, depending of the input do something different (windows batch file)

Tags: windows, batch-file

My problem is that I have to make a for loop that asks the user to type something 5 times and then do something depending in the user answer, my idea was to put a if else inside the for loop but that makes the program crash. Is there a easy way to make this? Also sorry if my english is not the best.

My code idea:

```
@echo off

for /l /f %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (

    set /p option= type option
    
    if %option%==a (
        echo option a
    ) else (
        if %option%==b (
            echo option b
        ) else (
            echo another option
        )
    )
)

pause
exit
```

Comment: I don't think you can use both /l and /f

Comment: @Anders I used a loop with /l and /f, and it works if i dont use the if else, I tried not using both to see if it will fix the problem with the if else but it still crashes, but I will no longer use both just in case

Comment: This has been asked a million times before, you can't set and then read a %variable% in a for loop...

Comment: @Anders Yeah it definetly gives problems regardles of what its inside the for loop, my bad. The only thing to fix now is the if else, thanks!

Comment: @Anders I dint know that, sorry. Im still new to batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below:

Changes:
removed /f from for-loop (syntax errors)
moved if-construct to subroutine (avoids need for delayedexpansion)
changed exit to exit/b (easier to run from commandline in cmd)

Suggestions:
For easier detection of errors start with echo on.
Run the batchfile from the commandline.
Replace the set/p with the choice command.

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    set /p option= type option
    call :sub
)
pause
exit/b

:sub
    if %option%==a (
        echo option a
    ) else (
        if %option%==b (
            echo option b
        ) else (
            echo another option
        )
    )
exit/b
```